# How do i print out the JAVA classpath in gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am currently using gradle integration with ecplise. Is there a way to print out the classpath of a javaexec task?

Answer (score 17):

The simplest would be to set log level to info using `--info`

If you would like to not browse through the output you could add a line similar to this inside your JavaExec task

```
doFirst{
  sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.each { println it}
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.asPath
```

For printing, you can write below the line in your task:

```
println "Classpath = ${sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.asPath}";
```

Answer (score 3):

Or add  `println configurations.runtime.resolve()` to your `build.gradle`.

Comment: This gives me:

> Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':compile' after it has been included in dependency resolution.

Comment: @ToddiusZho, this means that you have tried to change the dependencies after this line. You might just move the line to the end of the file. However, if the build script is complex enough, it might still not work. It is probably better to but the line into a task.

Answer (score 3):

With gradle v4 I was unable to get either of the above options to work, but using `--debug` and `grep classpath` did find the information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use gradle/gradlew command for that:

```
./gradlew dependencies --configuration compileClasspath
```

or for the runtime classpath:

```
./gradlew dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath
```

Comment: configuration 'compileClasspath' not found in configuration container.

Answer (score 0):

I add this task to all my gradle projects (`build.gradle.kts` syntax below):

```
tasks.register("saveClassPathToFile") {
    doFirst {
        File("classpath.txt").writeText(sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath.asPath)
    }
}
```

Then in the shell:

```
$ ./gradlew saveClassPathToFile
$ export CLASSPATH=`cat classpath.txt`
$ java com.example.MyEntryPoint
...
```